# How to access Spring Boot Quartz Bean from another module?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring Boot project that is going to be using Quartz to manage the running of some scripts. The project layout is as follows:

```
scheduler
|
|__scheduler-api
|  |
|  |__quartz-bean
|
|__scheduler-composition
   |
   |__service-to-schedule-quartz-jobs-using-quartz-bean
```

The api module is a Spring Boot application where the quartz bean lives. The composition module is where my services live that will be used to add jobs and triggers to Quartz. The problem I am running into is that my Quartz bean is not accessible from the composition module, therefore I am not able to schedule jobs in my service like I'd want to. My Quartz bean is defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
class QuartzScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext? = null

    @Autowired
    private val databaseConfiguration: DatabaseConfiguration? = null

    @Bean
    fun springBeanJobFactory(): SpringBeanJobFactory {
        val jobFactory = AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory()
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext!!)
        return jobFactory
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(SchedulerException::class)
    fun scheduler(@Qualifier("schedulerFactoryBean") factory: SchedulerFactoryBean): Scheduler {
        val scheduler = factory.scheduler   
        scheduler.start()
        return scheduler
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun schedulerFactoryBean(): SchedulerFactoryBean {
        val factory = SchedulerFactoryBean()
        factory.setDataSource(databaseConfiguration!!.dataSource())
        factory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory())
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties())
        return factory
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun quartzProperties(): Properties {
        val propertiesFactoryBean = PropertiesFactoryBean()
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"))
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject()!!
    }
}
```

A couple things I've tried include moving the Quarts bean to the composition module, but then it doesn't have access to the database configuration it needs. I also tried importing the api module into the composition module but it created a circular dependency. Can someone help me access the Quartz bean from my composition module? I'm new to Spring Boot so I am not really sure where I am going wrong or what my options are even. Thanks!

**Edit**

My service looks like this:

```
class QuartzService {

    @Autowired
    private var quartzScheduler: QuartzScheduler? = null

    fun upsertJob(job: JobEntity) {
        var jobExists = quartzScheduler!!.scheduler().checkExists(JobKey.jobKey(job.id.toString()))
        if (!jobExists) {
            quartzScheduler!!.scheduler().addJob(
                    newJob().ofType(EnqueueJob::class.java).storeDurably().withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(job.id.toString())).build(),
                    true
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The error that appears is that the type QuartzScheduler cannot be found (my QuartzScheduler class from `scheduler-api`)

Comment: Are you using Maven/Gradle? If so, are you expressing the dependency between `scheduler-composition` module and `scheduler-api` module?

Comment: @user2340612 I am using Gradle. I added the dependency to `scheduler-composition` but it created a circular reference because `scheduler-api` also depends on `scheduler-composition`. Am I out of luck here?

Comment: Sorry I suggested the wrong thing, that'd be a compile time dependency, not a runtime one. So at runtime your `scheduler` bean should be visible as long as both modules run as part of the same spring boot application. What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: @user2340612 When I try to `@Autowired` the bean in my Quartz service the type is unrecognized. It won't compile. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use the Quartz bean?

Comment: If it doesn't compile then there's a problem with your Gradle dependencies. Where is the error? If it's on `@Autowired` then you're missing spring dependencies, while if it's the `Scheduler` then you're missing Quartz dependencies

Comment: @user2340612 I added my Quartz service class to show you how I'm using it. Very well could be incorrect.

Comment: You can create a factory class and do some sort of injection upon instantiating the jobs. It's actually quite easy

Comment: @TheRealChx101 You think this would be possible given my code samples? I guess I'm not sure where to begin with something like that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of problems going on. First, my Quartz service was auto wiring the scheduler improperly. I changed it to this:

```
class QuartzService {

    @Autowired
    private lateint var scheduler: Scheduler

    fun upsertJob(job: JobEntity) {
        var jobExists = scheduler.checkExists(JobKey.jobKey(job.id.toString()))
        if (!jobExists) {
            scheduler.addJob(
                    newJob().ofType(EnqueueJob::class.java).storeDurably().withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(job.id.toString())).build(),
                    true
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I had to change the class that was using the Quartz service to auto wire the service, I accidentally just instantiated it as a normal object:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var quartzService: QuartzService
```

Thanks everyone for the help!